# detect duplicate email adresses in array

Tags: typescript

So I have the following problem and I cant figure out how to fix it. I had to program a usermanager in typescript with an html input form, this works very well, but the only thing that wont work is the email check to detect if an email adress is already used by someone and the user has to take another email adress to register.
the class user(name, email, passwort) is saved in the array userlist. Ive already tried to check the array with an for loop, but this wont work?

```
    form.addEventListener("submit", (event: Event) => {

    event.preventDefault();

    vorname = (document.getElementById("fname") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    nachname = (document.getElementById("lname") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    email = (document.getElementById("email") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    passwort = (document.getElementById("passwort") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    let passwortcheck: string = (document.getElementById("passwortcheck") as HTMLInputElement).value;

    let user: User = new User();

    user.vorname = vorname;
    user.nachname = nachname;
    user.email = email;
    user.passwort = passwort;
    passwortalt = user.passwort;

    for (let i: number = 0; i <= userlist.length; i++) {
        if (user.passwort === passwortcheck && user.email != userlist[i].email) {
            userlist.push(user);
            form.reset();
            renderUserlist();
        } else {
            alert("Passwörter stimmen nicht überein");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: in the first part of this if its a "repeat password" check. this works well but as soon as I add the for loop for checking the emails it stops working

Comment: try with   user.email !== userlist[i].email instead of  && user.email != userlist[i].email

Comment: does not work...

Comment: are you getting any errors? , Can you please share a codesandbox link?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-thompson-ouuyz?file=/index.html hope ive done this right

Comment: script.js:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (script.js:32) this is the error: line 32 = if (user.passwort === passwortcheck && user.email !== userlist[i].email) {

Comment: your loop condition is incorrect, looks like your userlist is empty initially .change it to  (let i: number = 0; i <userlist.length; i++)

Comment: unfortunately thats not the answer

Comment: did you tried using i < userlist.length; on your loop? are you getting any error?

Comment: I see your sandbox link, can you please add some code, so I can run it and take look?

Comment: shouldn't be empty, ive already added the code

Comment: Somehow I see the empty file on the above code sandbox, can you please check if the link is correct?

Comment: okay check again

Answer (score 1):

so i fixed the problem by myself... :)

```
    for (let i: number = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) {
        if (user.email == userlist[i].email) {
            alert("EMail bereits registriert!");
            return emailgleich;
        }
    }
    if (user.passwort === passwortcheck && emailgleich != true) {
        console.log(emailgleich);
        userlist.push(user);
        form.reset();
        renderUserlist();
    } else {
        alert("Passwörter stimmen nicht überein");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `some` method of JavaScript array to simplify this

```
const emailAlreadyTaken: boolean = userlist.some((value: User) => value.email === user.email);
```